# Rails: wicked_pdf "file_name" option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation

I got wicked_pdf working, but one of the render options is `file_name` which as far as I can tell has no bearing at all on the PDF rendering.  Can someone explain to me what exactly this is for?

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => "file_name"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ultimately [passed to](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/faa3c0d5f21be4e54293fecde930244288c69802/lib/wicked_pdf/pdf_helper.rb#L89) Rails' [`send_data`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data) method as the `filename` option, which:

> :filename - suggests a filename for the browser to use.

So when you say:

`format.pdf { render pdf: 'the_answer' }`

It becomes:

`send_data(pdf_content, :filename => 'the_answer.pdf',..`

---

The `send_data` method uses this (with other options) to set the `Content-Disposition` header in the response. If you inspect the response (e.g. in Chrome's Developer Tools) you will see:

`Content-Disposition:inline; filename="the_answer.pdf"`

How the browser implements this is ultimately up to it, but in Chrome you can see it by right clicking on the PDF and clicking 'Save as...'

[image: save file dialog]

---

**Note:** The presence of the `:pdf` key is [used to decide whether wicked_pdf should handle it](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/faa3c0d5f21be4e54293fecde930244288c69802/lib/wicked_pdf/pdf_helper.rb#L18), so it must be specified if you wish you use this `render` helper.

Comment: I have [raised an issue](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/488) to have the documentation clarified.